# Bootstrap responsive image layout - resize

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using this bootstrap template as my base: http://startbootstrap.com/templates/grayscale/ and I'm trying to get the same result but instead of GRAYSCALE big text I'd like to use an image that is 421x515px.

My problem is that in the original page (see link above) those down arrows stay visible no matter the screen resolution. I'm having problems in replicating that. Can anyone help me please?

I've used "img-responsive" class for the image, but it doesnt seem to work (not resizing the image as it should).

Anyone willing to help? Thanks.

Edit: Example link here: http://jsfiddle.net/x8EpU/5/

```
<img src="http://placehold.it/421x515" class="img-responsive">
```

Comment: Can you show what code you've done? Put up a link from [Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/new) or [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Added link on original post. Please refresh and check

Comment: I don't see any boostrap css file linked in your jsfiddle.

Comment: @notme He's got it in external resources.


OP, I can't replicate the down arrows staying visible in the template or in the fiddle. You want the arrows visible at all times?

Comment: Bootstrap CSS is linked as an external resource (see External Resources tab), but I've added the original css as well. Please check the new link: http://jsfiddle.net/x8EpU/5/

Comment: @Reck thats what I need, for bootstrap lg, md, sm resolutions. My guess, and tell me if i'm wrong, but the image needs to be resized to fit the button as well, correct?

Comment: @Reck I dont care about the button shape, it can just be a simple default button for all I care

Comment: I don't see any issues beside you having a really tall image. Looks fine here: http://www.bootply.com/eslZjc2UDi

Answer (score 0):

The down arrows don't actually stay visible at any resolution. Try making your browser really short and they will eventually be off the screen. It's actually just centering the entire block vertically (title, text, and arrows) but if the screen is shorter than this content it doesn't look right.

In your code, you've made the size of the block larger than the height of your screen by using such a large image. Try zooming out your browser a few times and you can see it working right, even with the image.

Try removing the `img-responsive` class on the `img` and adding the following style: `max-width: 100%; max-height: 150px;`